# Preferring mutable or immutable collections as method parameters

Tags: java, immutability

I'm writing a library method that will be used in several places. One of the method's parameters is a collection of objects, and the method does not mutate this collection. Should the method signature specify a mutable or immutable collection?

### Option 1: mutable collection as parameter

```
public static void foo(List<Bar> list) {
  // ...
}
```

Pros: Clients can pass in whichever of `List<Bar>` or `ImmutableList<Bar>` is more convenient for them.

Cons: It is not immediately obvious that the `list` parameter will not be mutated. Clients must read documentation and/or code to realize this. Clients may make unnecessary defensive copies anyway.

### Option 2: immutable collection as parameter

```
public static void foo(ImmutableList<Bar> list) {
  // ...
}
```

Pros: Clients have a guarantee that the `list` parameter will not be mutated.

Cons: If the client has a `List<Bar>`, they must first convert it to an `ImmutableList<Bar>` before calling `foo`. This conversion wastes a small amount of time, and it is *forced* on clients whether they like it or not.

---

Note: For the purposes of this question, let's assume that all clients will have Guava's `ImmutableList` available, for example because the library and client code all belong to the same codebase that already uses `ImmutableList` elsewhere.

Comment: I don't see a reason to force the collection to be immutable. Even if you don't mutate the collection, what's the benefit of forcing it to be immutable?

Comment: @VinceEmigh There's a general notion that immutability is preferred wherever it can apply. I'm wondering if this scenario is stretching that guiding principle too far since it limits the flexibility of the library function. Also, Option 2 provides a _guarantee_ while Option 1 can only document a promise (that may be later broken unintentionally).

Comment: @pkpnd you can test for immutability and throw unsupported operation exception and still use List.

Comment: `Collections.frequency` - Would we have to convert our collections to immutable collections before checking the frequency of an element? @Schred Didn't mean for the statement to be taken so literally. I was suggesting it wouldn't add value, so I don't see any point in forcing it (just to let the clients know their list won't be mutated). Not saying I'm right either, just my lonely opinion, seems like it's an attempt to "help" the client, but really it puts more work on them.

Comment: The question doesn't seem like an actual problem, rather curiosity about best practices. This question is probably better fit for [Software Engineering Stack Exchange](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/), as that's where design concepts are typically discussed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the creator of the `foo()` API, this is none of your business. You take a list and you don't modify it, and that's it. Your code, in fact, doesn't care about the list's mutability (it's a concern of the caller): so document your intent and stop there.

If the caller needs to guarantee that the list will not be tampered with, they would create defensive copies **not** because you don't promise to leave the list unchanged, but because **they** need that guarantee.

It's following the same logic that we perform null checks in method implementations: it's needed because *our* code needs to be robust, not because the caller can send a null argument.

In other words, document your method as you intend to implement them, and leave it up to the caller to pick the list implementation. The reasons of their choices will vary (i.e., it won't always be only whether you'll modify the list).

Comment: It can make sense for the api method to be imutable or test for immutability, if the API method is a client to other potentialy mutable methods. And the particular methid knows for sure that mutating the original list would e undesired.

Comment: Just to be sure, is your answer recommending Option 1 because it's the more general case? Of course it's up to the caller to decide whether they have a `List` or `ImmutableList` but I still need to decide on Option 1 or 2.

Comment: @AlexandarPetrov In this case, *you* effectively don't care about the list's mutability. The caller does, so they'll deal with it. If you needed the list to be mutable, you'd document that fact and throw exceptions when an unmodifiable list is sent in. I think option 2 is a way to obsess about just one of many characteristics that the caller may need to worry about.

Comment: @pkpnd "Option 1", except that `List` does not take on mutability.

Comment: @ernest_k The example is generic. You cant draw the conclusion you are drawing only from the example.

Comment: @AlexandarPetrov There's no conclusion drawn. I'm reducing this to this simple logic: the method should not add unnecessary constraints. If I don't care about a given attribute of a parameter, I should avoid limiting the caller on it. Extend that to this example, and you get the feedback I gave.

Comment: @AlexandarPetrov Maybe my answer would help convince you. However, the answer Ernest gave nails the situation on the head at it's core. This shouldn't even be an issue to invest time on. It's an issue introduced by trying to force "best practice", and if "best practice" wasn't trying to be enforced here, I think it would make the OP's time on his project a lot more productive.

Answer (score 1):

Leave it at `List`.

Here are some situations to consider:

- `Collections.synchronizedCollection` does not modify the client's collection.

  - If it forced clients to input an immutable collection, there'd be no use in making it a synchronized collection, since an immutable collection would already be thread safe.
- `Collections.frequency` does not modify the client's collection.

  - To check frequency, users would be forced to endure the excess overhead of transferring elements to a new collection.

These reasons aren't why the JDK doesn't expose an immutable interface. Those reasons are explained [in the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/doc-files/coll-designfaq.html#a1). In the case of `synchronizedCollection`, although it doesn't modify the client's collection, it does return a modifiable view of the client's collection; some would say this function wouldn't apply here. However, `frequency` and other query functions still hold strong.

You shouldn't restrict clients for the purpose of trying to advertise safety and nothing more. There should be more justification, otherwise your attempt to help could be a burden on the client. In some cases, your goal can be contradictive to what the function/system is achieving, such as with the `synchronizedCollection` example.

It's good to encourage safety, but having your system force it onto your clients without the system benefiting from it would be abuse of power; that's not your decision to make.

---

ernest_k makes a really good point [in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61652108/2398375), suggesting that you need to analyze what your system should be in charge of, and what the client should be in charge of. In this case, it should be up to the client whether the collection is immutable or not, since your system doesn't care about mutability. As he put it, "*it's none of your business*", which I agree with.